# Map generation, issues with midpoint displacement algorithm

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, maps, terrain

I'm trying to generate an endless 2d terrain. So the terrain isn't random per say as the random function I'm using is a hash based on an X,Y coordinate.

```
static public float rand (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y) {
    /* mix around the bits in x: */
    x = x * 3266489917 + 374761393;
    x = (x << 17) | (x >> 15);

    /* mix around the bits in y and mix those into x: */
    x += y * 3266489917;

    /* Give x a good stir: */
    x *= 668265263;
    x ^= x >> 15;
    x *= 2246822519;
    x ^= x >> 13;
    x *= 3266489917;
    x ^= x >> 16;

    /* trim the result and scale it to a float in [0,1) */
    return (x & 0x00ffffff) * (1.0f / 0x1000000);
}
```

I also have a scaled random function that scales the random number down a bit

```
static public float scaledRand (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y, uint scale) {
    return rand (x, y) / scale;
}
```

So given a X,Y coordinate I find its bounding box (the portion of the overall map I'm working with.

```
static private UIntRect getBounds (uint x, uint y) {
    UIntRect bounds = new UIntRect ();
    bounds.xMin = (uint)(Mathf.FloorToInt (x / GridSize) * GridSize);
    bounds.yMin = (uint)(Mathf.FloorToInt (y / GridSize) * GridSize);
    bounds.xMax = bounds.xMin + GridSize;
    bounds.yMax = bounds.yMin + GridSize;

    return bounds;
}
```

I then create a bunch of noise with the above random function

```
static private void createNoise(ref Tile[,] tiles, uint x, uint y) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < GridSize; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < GridSize; j++) {
            tiles [i, j] = new Tile ();
            tiles [i, j].data = rand (x + i, y + j);
        }
    }
}
```

If I just map out the noise I get

[image: Random]

I have a midpoint displacement algorithm

```
static private void midpointDisplacement (ref Tile[,] tiles, uint roughness, uint x, uint y) {
    // Diamond algorithm
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 X 0
    // 0 0 0
    for (uint i = 1; i < GridSize - 1; i += 2) {
        for (uint j = 1; j < GridSize - 1; j += 2) {
            float a = tiles[i - 1, j - 1].data;
            float b = tiles[i - 1, j + 1].data;
            float c = tiles[i + 1, j - 1].data;
            float d = tiles[i + 1, j + 1].data;
            tiles [i, j].data = Mathf.Clamp01(((a + b + c + d) / 4) + scaledRand(x + i, y + j, roughness));
        }
    }

    // Square algorithm
    // 0 1 0
    // 1 0 1
    // 0 1 0
    for (uint i = 0; i < GridSize - 1; ++i) {
        uint start = 0;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            start = 1;
        }
        for (uint j = start; j < GridSize - 1; j += 2) {
            // get surrounding values
            float a = 0, b = a, c = a, d = a;
            if (i != 0) a = tiles[i - 1, j].data;
            if (j != 0) b = tiles[i, j - 1].data;
            if (j + 1 != GridSize -1) c = tiles[i, j + 1].data;
            if (i + 1 != GridSize -1) d = tiles[i + 1, j].data;

            // average calculation
            if (i == 0) tiles [i, j].data = (b + c + d) / 3;
            else if (j == 0) tiles [i, j].data = (a + c + d) / 3;
            else if (j + 1 == GridSize -1) tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + d) / 3;
            else if (i + 1 == GridSize -1) tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + c) / 3;
            else tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + c + d) / 4;

            tiles [i, j].data = Mathf.Clamp01(tiles [i, j].data + scaledRand(x + i, y + j, roughness));
        }

    }

}
```

If I run the map through the algorithm once I get

[image: MPD 1 time]

Things don't look much smoother no large areas of high or low ground. It looks basically like the noise did.

If I run the map through the algorithm 5 times I still get basically noise, No large areas of low/high ground.

[image: MPD 5 times]

Each time I'm calling the algorithm I'm setting the roughness to smooth things out, or at least thats the hope

```
static public Tile getTile (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y) {
    UIntRect bounds = getBounds (x, y);
    uint localX = x - bounds.xMin;
    uint localY = y - bounds.yMin;

    Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[GridSize, GridSize];
    createNoise (ref tiles, x, y);
    for (uint i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        midpointDisplacement (ref tiles, i * 10, x, y);
    }

    return tiles [localX, localY];
}
```

The only other thing that may be effecting things is the tile type function. Basically the map data is a float between 0 and 1. I only have 2 tile types at the moment high and low. So I'm turning the float into 0 or 1 in the Tile class

```
public class Tile {
    public float data = 0f;
    public int type {
        get {
            return Mathf.RoundToInt (data * 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

The full Terrain class is here

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Terrain {
    public class Tile {
        public float data = 0f;
        public int type {
            get {
                return Mathf.RoundToInt (data * 1f);
            }
        }
    }

    private class UIntRect {
        public uint xMin;
        public uint xMax;
        public uint yMin;
        public uint yMax;
    }

    private const uint GridSize = 32;
    private const int a = 0x7fffffff / 48271;
    private const int b = 0x7fffffff % 48397;

    static public float rand (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y) {
        /* mix around the bits in x: */
        x = x * 3266489917 + 374761393;
        x = (x << 17) | (x >> 15);

        /* mix around the bits in y and mix those into x: */
        x += y * 3266489917;

        /* Give x a good stir: */
        x *= 668265263;
        x ^= x >> 15;
        x *= 2246822519;
        x ^= x >> 13;
        x *= 3266489917;
        x ^= x >> 16;

        /* trim the result and scale it to a float in [0,1) */
        return (x & 0x00ffffff) * (1.0f / 0x1000000);
    }

    static public float scaledRand (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y, uint scale) {
        return rand (x, y) / scale;
    }

    static public Tile getTile (System.UInt32 x, System.UInt32 y) {
        UIntRect bounds = getBounds (x, y);
        uint localX = x - bounds.xMin;
        uint localY = y - bounds.yMin;

        Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[GridSize, GridSize];
        createNoise (ref tiles, x, y);
        for (uint i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            midpointDisplacement (ref tiles, i * 10, x, y);
        }

        return tiles [localX, localY];
    }

    static private void createNoise(ref Tile[,] tiles, uint x, uint y) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < GridSize; i++) {
            for (uint j = 0; j < GridSize; j++) {
                tiles [i, j] = new Tile ();
                tiles [i, j].data = rand (x + i, y + j);
            }
        }
    }

    static private void midpointDisplacement (ref Tile[,] tiles, uint roughness, uint x, uint y) {
        // Diamond algorithm
        // 0 0 0
        // 0 X 0
        // 0 0 0
        for (uint i = 1; i < GridSize - 1; i += 2) {
            for (uint j = 1; j < GridSize - 1; j += 2) {
                float a = tiles[i - 1, j - 1].data;
                float b = tiles[i - 1, j + 1].data;
                float c = tiles[i + 1, j - 1].data;
                float d = tiles[i + 1, j + 1].data;
                tiles [i, j].data = Mathf.Clamp01(((a + b + c + d) / 4) + scaledRand(x + i, y + j, roughness));
            }
        }

        // Square algorithm
        // 0 1 0
        // 1 0 1
        // 0 1 0
        for (uint i = 0; i < GridSize - 1; ++i) {
            uint start = 0;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                start = 1;
            }
            for (uint j = start; j < GridSize - 1; j += 2) {
                // get surrounding values
                float a = 0, b = a, c = a, d = a;
                if (i != 0) a = tiles[i - 1, j].data;
                if (j != 0) b = tiles[i, j - 1].data;
                if (j + 1 != GridSize -1) c = tiles[i, j + 1].data;
                if (i + 1 != GridSize -1) d = tiles[i + 1, j].data;

                // average calculation
                if (i == 0) tiles [i, j].data = (b + c + d) / 3;
                else if (j == 0) tiles [i, j].data = (a + c + d) / 3;
                else if (j + 1 == GridSize -1) tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + d) / 3;
                else if (i + 1 == GridSize -1) tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + c) / 3;
                else tiles [i, j].data = (a + b + c + d) / 4;

                tiles [i, j].data = Mathf.Clamp01(tiles [i, j].data + scaledRand(x + i, y + j, roughness));
            }

        }

    }

    static private UIntRect getBounds (uint x, uint y) {
        UIntRect bounds = new UIntRect ();
        bounds.xMin = (uint)(Mathf.FloorToInt (x / GridSize) * GridSize);
        bounds.yMin = (uint)(Mathf.FloorToInt (y / GridSize) * GridSize);
        bounds.xMax = bounds.xMin + GridSize;
        bounds.yMax = bounds.yMin + GridSize;

        return bounds;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to change things to make the resulting map less random
and more larger areas of high/low ground? I'm guessing my midpoint displacement stuff isn't working properly.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but maybe an alternative solution: http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-1/ Disclaimer, I made the AccidentalNoise port used in the tutorial.

Comment: @WilliamMariager - The Accidental Noise port you did is everything I needed. Thank you so much.